# how to debug when browser and phpstorm is in different computer

Tags: php

I installed the phpstorm and x-debug  in one computer whose os is centos,  I set one breakpoint , it can  stop at the breakpoint  when i   start the browser on this computer.    but if i start the browser on another computer whose os is macOS, when the code at the breakpoint is executed , it  didn’t stop ,why?  how to solve the problem?

I found that when I debug on the centos ,I clicked the debug button ,i opened the browser whose url is : 192.168.1.7/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=16889 , and it will stop at the breakpoint, but  when i opened the browser and opened the same url on another computer ,it didn't stop .

but i want it to stop ! how to do it. because i want to debug it with Chrome, so i can't open the browser   on the centos.

Now i am sure I have clicked Start Listening for php debug connection.
Now I installed  x-debug helper on the Chrome ,i think i need it ,and i set IDEKEY value PHPSTORM ,and adjust  x-debug helper to debug mode,and open the url http://192.168.1.7/index.php ,but it is still  not stop. (The chrome and   phpstorm  installed on different computer)

Comment: And you are certain that the http server is the same? It is only the client that gets executed on that other system? If so, then you have an issue with your debugging session on that client. Is the xdebug session id used on that client? Check your browsers console, the request details in there.

Comment: thank arkascha,http server is the same,i think if chrome and phpstorm are in different computer, i must use x-debug-helper,but it still didn't work.